# How can I add text emphasis to links in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, formatting, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap allows me to emphasize text in general through the use of the `text-*` class attribute on the `<p>` tag. However, when I nest a link inside, the link does not have the emphasis formatting applied (namely, color). Is there an attribute I could add to the anchor tag so that it will display the same emphasis as the `<p>` tag?

For example, the following code would have a green 'HW: Read this ' followed by a blue, underlined 'Link'

```
<p class="text-success"><strong>HW:</strong> Read this <a href="http://json.org/">Link</a></p>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit the color property for the anchor with this style:

```
.text-success a{
    color: inherit;
}
```

By default anchors do not inherit the color property of their parent.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7ZFpr/1/

Comment: Your fiddle work, but in Bootstrap the anchor still hasn't changes colors. In Chrome, I looked at matched styles, and it did say `color: #a94442;` inherited from p.text-danger (from bootstrap.min.css:7); however, further up (higher priority, I guess) in the styles was another bootstrap style, `a {color: #428bca;}`. Could that be overriding my custom color? If so, how do I tell it that my style is more important?

Comment: Use the latest bootstrap. If the class to inherit is after the global a color then it will work. http://jsbin.com/emeMUkOT/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the content inside of the anchor tag with a `span` containing the text class.

Example:

```
<a href="#"><span class="text-danger">I'm a red link</span></a>
```